# php .htaccess clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

xxx.com.com/front << work
retuern

```
Array ( [mod] => home  )
```

xxx.com/news-my-seo-title << work
return

```
Array ( [mod] => cat [act] => more [seo] => hiburan-2 )
```

xxx.com/cat-mycategory-1 << not work
return

```
Array ( [mod] => cat [act] => more [seo] => hiburan-2 )
```

i need return like

```
Array ( [mod] => cat [act] => more [seo] => hiburan [page]=> 2 )
```

what mistake i made, since this is my first time doing front page job so i need good clean url

by the way this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^front root.php?mod=home [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(news|sch|cat)-([^-].*)$ root.php?mod=$1&act=more&seo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(news|sch|cat)-([^-].*)-([0-9]+)$ root.php?mod=$1&act=more&seo=$2&page=$3 [L]

Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

hope some one could help me, many thank, and if there is link or any thing i can read please give me link.
additional info my seo title format like so (dash seperated)

```
this-is-seo-title
```

thanks before

Comment: Try changing `[^-].*` to `[^-]*` in both rules

Comment: it work many thanks 
the first rule it not work so i use the old one

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^front root.php?mod=home [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(news|sch|cat)-(.+)-(\d+)/?$ root.php?mod=$1&act=more&seo=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(news|sch|cat)-(.+)/?$ root.php?mod=$1&act=more&seo=$2 [L]
```

It's not possible to use `[^-]*` because you use `-` in seo title.